# regex not working "within" javascript string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to replace all mentions of [b] in a text string and replace it with `<b>`. The problem with what I'm using below this that it's replace every [b] on the page, and I only want it to change the [b]'s within the text string ("text") that I'm sending in.

Taking out the 'g' for global in the regex doesn't work very well because it then doesn't replace them all...

```
text = $("#input").val();

text = text.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\s|>)\\[b](\\S.*?\\S)\\[/b]($|\\s|<)', 'gim') , '$1<strong>$2</strong>$3');
```

any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Try `text = text.replace(/(^|\s|>)\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]($|\s|<)/gim, '$1<strong>$2</strong>$3');`

Comment: What do you mean by "on the page" and "within the text string"? The replace is operating on your `text` variable, so if that variable holds the whole page obviously it'll do replacements within the whole page. How do you set `text` before doing the replace?

Comment: it's either an input value or text of an element I'm passing in via jquery.text()

Comment: @Tim Yes, can you post a couple of reasonable input examples? Or should we invent them ourselves? Until you do that, you will get no answer.

Comment: @Tim Your regex is doing well: http://jsfiddle.net/avrelian/2eygB/. The problem is somewhere else. Try defining your `text` variable in the local scope.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what the problem is because the question is a bit unclear. Are you trying to replace the content within the textarea with the new html tags?

The following code is currently working for me in production:

```
text = $("#contract_body").val();  // strore the current contents
text = text.replace(/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/gim, "<strong>$1</strong>");  // replace bbcode with html tags
$("#contract_body").val(text);  // update the textarea with the new string contents
```

I hope that helps.