# Replace all instances of special character

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
 var whatever = 'Some [b]random[/b] text in a [b]sentence.[/b]';
```

How can I replace every instance of `[b]` with `<b>` and every instance of `[/b]` with `</b>` in jQuery?

I was attempting to do it with regex but I couldn't get it to function properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193190/regex-not-working-within-javascript-string

Comment: @UserIsCorrupt - OP - You should read all answers before picking one. Optimization is important: `1 < 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regex, it'd be:

```
whatever = whatever.replace(/\[b\]/g,'<b>').replace(/\[\/b\]/g,'</b>');
```

That'd seem to be the easiest solution

Comment: Why not combine them into one? Regex has `?` for the forward slash.

Comment: You'd need lookbehinds to correctly replace with <b> or </b>, which replace() doesn't support...at least not easily

Answer (score 3):

Elegant way:

```
whatever = whatever.replace(/\[(\/?)b\]/g,'<$1b>');
```

See and test it [here](http://ideone.com/nLmHT).

Comment: Well, looks like I was wrong about Javascript not supporting lookbehinds

Comment: @user1215106 Sorry, just personal preference.  I've always felt one of the driving things of SO was giving helpful answers that didn't necessarily require people to visit other sites just to put them in context.

Answer (score 0):

```
string.replace("[b]", "<b>");
```

Failing that, you could use PHP to do it using `str_replace` if it's being uploaded to a database.

Comment: This will only replace the first instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
whatever = whatever.replace(/\[b\]/g, '<br>').replace(/\[\/b\]/g, '</b>');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HmTx3/1/)**